# Как сделать переход по кнопке на новую php страницу в том случае, когда все поля на форме заполнены

Tags: html, form

Столкнулся с проблемой, что данные из формы отправляются даже в том случае, когда все поля пустые. Файл 'queries.php' служит для отправки данных 2-ух полей на другую страницу(для sql запроса). Грубо говоря мне нужно написать условие, что если поля пустые, то он ничего не делает, а если заполнены, то отправляет на страницу queries.php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<form class="form" action="queries.php" method="post">
<input placeholder="Откуда: Например, Москва" required="" type="text" name="where_by">
<input placeholder="Куда: Например, Санкт-Петербург" required="" type="text" name="where_to">
<input type="text" required="" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Введите дату отправления">
<input type="submit" value="Найти" onclick="location.href='https://sokolikovyan.ru/site/src/queries.php'">
</form>
```

Вот код этой формы. Если я не ошибаюсь, то решение моей проблемы лежит через использование ajax, но я так и не смог разобраться с этим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Пример на jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/0ux8cj99/7/)

```js
$('#send').click(function() {
  if ($('#whence').val().length < 1 || $('#where').val().length < 1 || $('#date').val().length < 1) {
    alert('Заполните все поля');
  } else {
    $('#form').submit();
  }
});
```

```css
.form {
  background: #FF3333;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 420px;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

button {
  width: 415px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <form id="form" action="https://sokolikovyan.ru/site/src/queries.php" class="form" method="post">
    <input id="whence" placeholder="Откуда: Например, Москва" required type="text" name="where_by">
    <br>
    <input id="where" placeholder="Куда: Например, Санкт-Петербург" required type="text" name="where_to">
    <br>
    <input type="text" required id="date" name="date" placeholder="Введите дату отправления">
    <br>
    <button id="send">Найти</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Скажи, а там и должно быть 2 атрибута "action"?

Comment: Нет не должно, исправил. Вместо "1" минимальное количество символов

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, разобрался))